# How can i plus a integer value after get sum result using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually, I want to get integer value this is working when i'm inserting value suppose i insert value `4+5` in input then I'm getting it in my result then I'm gettting it in another div with result like if I get `4+5` then it should be 9.

But i'm getting `[object Object]`

What is wrong in my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
    $('button').click(function(){
         var oldValue;
         var getValue;
        var boxValue;
        
        oldValue = $('.box').text();
        getValue = $('.getValue').val();
       boxValue = $('.box').text(oldValue + getValue);
        
        $('.finalResult').text(boxValue);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button> 
    <input type="text" class="getValue">
    
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="finalResult"></div>
```

Comment: `$('.finalResult').text(oldValue + getValue)` should solve

Comment: What's the value of `oldValue`? What it is holding and what is its type?

Comment: So you are setting text() with a jQuery object!

Comment: @Medet Tleukabiluly i'm getting same value on both result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
    $('button').click(function(){
         var oldValue;
         var getValue;
         var boxValue;
        
        oldValue = $('.box').text();
        getValue = $('.getValue').val();
        boxValue = $('.box').text(oldValue + getValue);
        
        $('.finalResult').text(Number(oldValue || '0') + eval(getValue));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button> 
    <input type="text" class="getValue">
    
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="finalResult"></div>
```

Comment: your code is working fine but what use of `eval()` in this code?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
    $('button').click(function(){
         var oldValue;
         var getValue;
         var boxValue;
        
        oldValue = $('.box').text();
        getValue = $('.getValue').val();
        if(!isNaN(oldValue) && !isNaN(getValue) )
        {
       boxValue = $('.box').text(oldValue + getValue);// in this line you are setting a value and assignig it to boxValue
        $('.finalResult').text(boxValue.text());//I am replacing this line
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Button</button> 
    <input type="text" class="getValue">
    
    <div class="box">0</div>
    <div class="finalResult"></div>
```

see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/7jde48u3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your ultimate goal is, but the [Object Object] occurs because you are placing the jQuery representation of .box into the DOM, which is an object.

Try changing these lines ...

```
    oldValue = +$('.box').text() || 0;
    getValue = +$('.getValue').val();

    $('.finalResult').text(boxValue.text());
```

The first two lines are one way to ensure you have a number; the last places the correct "text".

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `[objec object]` because you are actually trying to set an object in the div, below see the problem line. What you are doing is that you calculate the some and set the result .finalResult div but you are actually assigning the div to a variable and jquery is treating that variable as an object

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').click(function(){
         var oldValue;
         var getValue;
        var boxValue;

        oldValue = $('.box').text();
        getValue = $('.getValue').val();
       boxValue = $('.box').text(oldValue + getValue); //<-- problem

        $('.finalResult').text(boxValue);
    });
});
```

change the following line

```
$('.finalResult').text(boxValue);
```

with this one

```
$('.finalResult').text(boxValue.text());
```